# Capybara with PhantomJS / Poltergeist: Selecting value from drop-down doesn't trigger Ajax call

Tags: ruby, phantomjs, capybara, html-select, poltergeist

For non-commercial purposes I am trying to build a scraper. I have worked with PhantomJS before, and it usually works like a charm. However, I have stumbled upon the following problem:

What I want to do:

- Go to http://de.soccerway.com/national/germany/bundesliga/2010-2011/regular-season/r11840/
- Click on the button 'per Spieltag'
- Then select an option from the drop-down menu that holds the matchdays
- Wait for Ajax call to be complete and then get the information I need

Unfortunately, I can select the option I want to select, but nothing happens afterwards. I created a mini script to demonstrate this behavior:

```
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
require 'capybara/dsl'
include Capybara::DSL

Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, :js_errors => false)
end

Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.default_wait_time = 20
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = true
Capybara.current_session.driver.resize(1200, 1000)

visit('http://de.soccerway.com/national/germany/bundesliga/2010-2011/regular-season/r11840/')

# click on button 'per Spieltag'
find(:xpath, ".//a[text() = 'per Spieltag']").click

# drop down menu with matchdays
matchday_selector = find(:xpath, ".//select[@name='page']")

# save screenshot 'before'
save_screenshot('before.png', full: true)

# for demonstration purposes, select option with value '5'
matchday_selector.find(:xpath, ".//option[@value='5']").select_option

# wait some time for ajax call to be complete and save screenshot 'after'
sleep 5
save_screenshot('after.png', full: true)
```

If you compare the before and after screenshots, you will see that the number of the drop-down menu has changed, but the content of the table didn't. Also, the dropdown menus are not displayed at the correct position, but instead are shown in the top left corner of the screenshot.

If I use Selenium as my default driver, then it works, but I'd rather user PhantomJS because it is much faster in my experience.

How can I get PhantomJS to trigger the Ajax call?

I use PhantomJS 1.9.1, Capybara 2.1.0 and Poltergeist 1.3.0

Comment: Your code doesn't throw any exceptions. Also I see "6" selected in Spieltag at after.png

Comment: I removed the exceptions in this example - they are there in my real code. The 6 results because the count of values starts at 0, whereas the corresponding option in the drop-down menu starts at 1. So value 5 has stored a 6.

Comment: As I said your code works for me so I can't reproduce your issue

Comment: Ah, sorry, misunderstood. The code doesn't throw any exceptions on my computer, but the problem is that the website isn't updated, even though the drop-down option was selected. If you look at before.png and after.png, then the content of the table with the games should be different, but it stays the same in my case.

Comment: I reproduced it. It's a bug in Poltergeist as it's not reproducible in Selenium. You should report it there.